# Generating C# helper classes with XSD.exe: Failed handling imported schemas

Tags: c#, xml, import, xsd, xsd.exe

I would like to produce C# helper files from the [KML2.2 xml schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd) using the XSD.exe tool (from VS2008 SDK). With KML2.1, the tool worked just fine. However, the KML2.2 schema contains import tags pointing to [other schemas](http://docs.oasis-open.org/election/external/xAL.xsd) causing XSD.exe to freak out.

This is the error message I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Sample
s\Sdm> xsd.exe d:\temp\kml22.xsd /c /l:CS /n:Google.Kml22 /o:D:\temp\

Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3038]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom:author' element is
 not declared. Line 311, position 12.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom:link' element is not
 declared. Line 312, position 12.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0:Address
Details' element is not declared. Line 314, position 12.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce
 incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'd:\temp\kml22'.
  - The element 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom:author' is missing.
```

Do you have suggestions how could I generate my C# helper files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify all of the XSDs involved, including imports, in the command line. [Here's](http://www.power-programming.co.uk/post/2009/03/XSDexe-Schema-validation-warning.aspx) a blog post with an example.

Comment: Link is broken. Here is an archived version https://web.archive.org/web/20090719014029/http://www.power-programming.co.uk/post/2009/03/XSDexe-Schema-validation-warning.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick LinqPad script to make XSD.EXE do my bidding.. Copy/paste this into LinqPad, change the 3rd line to point to your XSD, press F5, and TADA!

```
void Main()
{
    var file = @"C:\.... some.xsd";
    Do(file);
    files.Dump();

    ("xsd.exe \"" + string.Join("\" \"", files) + "\" /classes").Dump();
}

private void Do(string file)
{
    file = file.ToLower();

    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
    var contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
    var regex = @"schemaLocation=""(.*?)""";

    if (files.Contains(file))
    {
        return;
    }

    files.Add(file);

    var toProcess = Regex.Matches(contents, regex).OfType<Match>().Select (m => m.Groups[1].Value).Select (m => 
    {
        if (Path.IsPathRooted(m))
        {
            return m;
        }
        else
        {
            return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(dir, m));
        }
    }).Select (m => m.ToLower()).Where (m => !files.Contains(m)).ToList();

    foreach (var nested in toProcess)
    {
        Do(nested);
    }
}
private List<string> files = new List<string>();
```

Read more about it at http://www.alexdresko.com/2015/10/08/xsd-exe-and-imports-a-solution/